# Laravel website 'uploaded on shared hosting' is showing directory structure instead of my specified web routes

Tags: laravel-5

I've uploaded the project on a shared hosting and it is showing the complete directory structure of the project.

I've searched for the solutions and changed my .htaccess file. This is my .htaccess file now:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

but it is still showing the same directory structure. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Laravel is not designed to run on shared hosting. You'll have to set it up differently to run on shared hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel is not designed to be run on shared hosting. You'll have to manually change its structure to run it on shared hosting.

Follow this article: https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e

Though I will recommend to buy a private server for laravel.